# android- How to customize actionbar tab

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar, customization

I'm using "Theme.AppCompat.Light" theme for my application in order to work with actionbar. 
I'm using android.support.v7 and this is the code I'm using for making the actionbar tabs :

```
    actionbar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionbar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    ActionBar.Tab tab1 = actionbar.newTab();
    tab1.setText("Tab 1");
    tab1.setTabListener(this);

    ActionBar.Tab tab2=actionbar.newTab();
    tab2.setText("Tab 2");
    tab2.setTabListener(this);

    ActionBar.Tab tab3=actionbar.newTab();
    tab3.setText("Tab 3");
    tab3.setTabListener(this);

    actionbar.addTab(tab1);
    actionbar.addTab(tab2);
    actionbar.addTab(tab3);
```

it works fine ( I wanted to post some images but I couldn't because of my reputation )

I wanna to do some customization like , change the height of tab , or when a tab is active, I wanna to change the background image  and some other sort of thing .

what should I do ? or where I can see actionbar tab styles and do my cusotmization?

thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a custom theme and set it to the `Activity` or whole application in `Manifest`

Create a custom action bar tab style like this, and change the required attributes

```
    <style name="MyActionBarTabView" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Base.ActionBar.TabView">
   <item name="android:background">@drawable/action_bar_tab_background</item>
   </style>
```

Create a custom theme like this, and change the `actionBarTabStyle`  attribute.

```
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.Base.AppCompat">
   <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabView</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabView</item>
    </style>
```